# Including content of URL in Swing Application or CGI Script in Swing

Tags: swing

I have an ip camera and I want to get the stream into my swing application. Since there seems not to be any streams available, the only option I have is the display the whole website or the cgi script.
The URL for the cgi script looks like this:

http: //IP/videostream.cgi?user=gast&pwd=

Is there a way to display the content to a swing container including refreshing the content? I will ask the company of the ip camera as well if there would be a stream available to caputre.

Answer (score 0):

The current view of the Cam is often included as an Image-Tag in the HTML-Side. You can download the Html Source an extract the Image URL. Now you can create an URL object in Java and download the Image from the URL Inputstream. You can convert the received bytes to an Image by using ImageIO.